# How to add that check in this function?

Tags: php, sql-server

I've added `$loyalty = $check["Loyalty"];` but I am not sure how to add check if `Loyalty` less than `2000` then show message: `You cannot register because you have less than 2000 Loyalty.`

http://pastebin.com/abDdgSA

I will greatly appreciate if someone show me how it should be done, so I won't break the code.
Thank you!

Comment: Use PHP's [`if()`](http://www.php.net/if) or SQL's `WHERE`

Comment: `if($loyalty < 2000) echo 'You cannot register...';` ?

Comment: Yeah, I did but my structure wasn't correct. Is it possible to let me know if you can place it in the code and let me see how it should look like to be correct in structure ?

Comment: Sorry, but you still need to write your own code (partly). Just try it, when it doesn't work and/or you get error messages, try something else

Answer (score 0):

```
$loyalty = $sorgu["Loyalty"];

$sorgu = doquery("SELECT COUNT(*) AS wrc FROM WRC_BDW_KAYIT WHERE StrAccountID = '".$acc."'", true);
$kyt=$sorgu["wrc"];

if($loyalty < 2000) {
    $geri = 'You cannot register because you have less than 2000 Loyalty.';
} else {

    if ( $kyt != "0" ) { // kayэtlэysa
        doquery("UPDATE WRC_BDW_KAYIT SET Zone = 0 WHERE StrAccountID = '".$acc."'");
        $geri = '<span style="color:#A2A2F1;" id="kayit">You are already registered.</span>';
    }
    else {
        doquery("INSERT INTO WRC_BDW_KAYIT VALUES ('".$char_id."', '".$acc."', 0, '".$css."', '".$nation."', '".$lwl."')");
        $geri = '<span style="color:green;" id="kayit">Congratulations!<br />You have successfully registered.</span>';
    }

}
```

Basic if statements, you've already got the data and you know **exactly** what you're checking for, what's the problem?

Comment: Ahh, but I want to include that in the $geri statement. How I can do that actually ? I just saw that it just echo it. I am sorry that I didnt specify it at first. Can I change `echo` to `$geri` and still works correctly actually ?

Comment: Greatly appreciated man. I will accept the answer, just 1 last question ? That's totally correct structure ? If less than 2000 Loyalty, the reset 2 `Already register....` and `Congratulations ...` wont even execute right? ... If more than 2000 Loyalty, it will execute.

Comment: I meant the statement you've added for me. But its stupid to ask since you made it that means it should be correct. Thank you a lot man. You got a beer from me!

Comment: Added `}` in the end. And it fixed thr 500 error. Its probably caused by it.

Comment: Correct - 500 errors are normally parse errors caused by missing syntax.

Comment: Yeah since the new if else required three } in the end instead of 2 only. I believe that correct.